# setup multisite into multi server

Tags: multi-sites

I developed multi site using Drupal 7.

1. example.com
2. site1.example.com
3. site2.example.com

All subdomains are using the same codebase in /sites/site1 and /sites/site2.

Is it possible to host SITE1 in a different hosting server with the same codebase?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this article:
**Multi-site - Sharing the same code base**
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite-drupal/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base

1. Create directories for your each site
2. Copy config files to each directory
3. Create a database for each site
4. Make a symbolic link for each site:

   $ ln -s . site1
   $ ln -s . site2